# Can someone identify this font (sorry for the static )

Tags: font-identification, japanese

[image]

I need it for art, I wana change “ 新宿肉屋 “ to “ 新宿肉交肉体  “

Comment: 'Shinjuku Meat Shop', in *that* colour? Starting to wonder what *kind* of meat we're talking about here...

Answer (score 2):

Mincho fonts all look quite similar, but I'm pretty sure this is Toppan Bunkyu Midashi Mincho Extrabold:

[image: (the characters 新宿肉屋 rendered in this font)]